# Angular nvd3 line chart length

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, charts, nvd3.js

I have a line chart. It is ploting okay. I need to show the chart on mobile devices. How do I optimize length of the chart on different devices?
When data set is large, the chart resizes and becomes very short lengthwise.

I have had some limited success with following css

```
.plot {
    height :480px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But I think I need some help now...

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid col-sm-10">
<nvd3-line-chart
    data="data3"
    id="growthChart"
    xAxisTickFormat="xAxisTickFormatFunction()"
    yAxisTickFormat="yAxisTickFormatFunction()"        
    showXAxis="true"
    showYAxis="true"
    >
        <div class="plot">
        <svg ></svg>
        </div>
</nvd3-line-chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved it.

```
.plot {
   min-height :480px;
   height :480px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

It is looking good as of now...

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if the solution solves the question

Comment: I am not very regular user here, how do I accept it as a solution. It is my own answer, I dont see an option to accept it as solution.

Comment: There should be tick icon on the left side of you answer.